# Cannot use map() while using swr in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

I am trying to get a list of users from API and then use `map` on every user to print the name, but I am not able to use it on the data.

I tried many different things and solutions on the internet but now it has been an hour and I can't fix this. Please help in solving this

```js
import "./App.css"
import useSWR from "swr"

function App() {
  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
  const { people } = useSWR(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    fetcher,
    { suspense: true }
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {people.map((person) => {
        <div>{person.name}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I am using `fetch` and I did check if I am getting something in return or not and YES I am getting the data but can't use `map` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you are using the `.map` function, here in your example it does not return anything, you have to use either an implicit return `=>(...)`

```js
{people.map((person) =>  
    <div>{person.name}</div>
)}
```

or an explicit return `=>{return(...)}`

```js
{people.map((person) => {
   return <div>{person.name}</div> 
})}
```

Note also that every child should have a unique `key` prop and better to map through `people` only when it is defined:

```js
{people && people.map((person, index) =>  
    <div key={index}>{person.name}</div> // better to use and 'person.id' or any other unique value as 'key'
)}
```

Comment: With every option I am getting `people is undefined` and the last one doesn't show anything because we put a check condition. But still I cant get anything to display as `people` is undefined and can't access `map` for it

Comment: I checked in the `network` tab and the API call is going through and the response is there but it still says that `people` is undefined

Comment: I got it to work finally. The problem was it needs to be `data` instead of `people` and it needs `isLoading` to handle while data is fetched.

Comment: @Pulkit good to know that  but you said that that `people` is defined. Anyways, glad you solve it

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are trying to map `people` before it has been fetched initially.

You can do 1 of two things to combat this:

```
{people && people.map((person) =>
    <div>{person.name}</div>
)}
```

OR

```
{people?.map((person) =>
    <div>{person.name}</div>
)}
```

These just check to make sure `people` actually has a value before it tries to `map` it and it won't throw an error if it's undefined.